# UK visa and regular income

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

So I applied for UK visa with a regular income of 129,429 . However , when I was paid it reflected in my account statement has 129,400 . I am worried that this little difference mine cause trouble with the Embassy

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You haven’t specified the currency you’re referring to, but a difference of 29 seems pretty insignificant. Did you provide paperwork to prove your income eg pay slips, employment contract etc?

Comment: It's a difference of about 0.02% so it shouldn't be much of an issue by itself, but the discrepancy may lead them to examine things more closely, so the rest of your application needs to be bulletproof.

Comment: If it's £129,400 (GBP) per annum, that will put you comfortably in the top 1% of incomes in the UK. A difference of £29  ( 0.025% ) is less than the daily currency fluctuations, so should be ignored when checking your income

Answer (score 4):

A discrepancy of less than 0.1% in your salary is not going to be a problem, no matter what the currency.

Answer (score 2):

Discrepancies with funds are one of the main reasons UK visa applications are rejected, however the discrepancies have to be materially significant to cause a problem. In your case, the difference is trivial and it won't have any effect on your application at all.

Visa officers know that salary payments going into bank accounts vary due to all sorts of factors and this is the same for most people regardless of currency. It would have to be a significant difference for it to have an impact on your application.

Comment: bon_vivant, please only post a link if it is not from a commercial site, as your post did run the risk of being deleted as a spam message, because of the link now taken out.